# Calling a function automatically when rendering a screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, expo, stack-navigator

So I have a header bar which I hide when I open a profile screen with stackNavigation

**ProfileScreen:**

```
export default class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        props.screenProps.updateHeader();
    }
// Code goes on
//..........
//................
//...........................
}
```

This calls updateHeader from parent class and then calls the function

**Main (Parent class):**

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showHeader: true
        };
    }

    updateState = () => {
        this.setState({
            showHeader: !this.state.showHeader
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {renderIf(this.state.showHeader,
                    <Header />
                )}
               <UserStack screenProps={{ updateHeader: this.updateState }} />
             </View>
        );
     }
}
```

It works but a little slow.

Will it work better when I export the project?

And I am also getting this warning:

**Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.**

What should I do to fix that?

Comment: well maybe calling `props.screenProps.updateHeader();` from the constructor is the problem? `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor).`

Comment: @ewizard you are right. Calling it from inside a button works but the problem is that my app navigates with swipes so it should call the function automatically each time the page renders

Comment: Oh i think the error message is telling you to use the lifecycle hook `componentWillMount`...try in your `ProfileScreen` component - `componentWillMount() { props.screenProps.updateHeader(); }` and take `props.screenProps...` out of the constructor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As **ewizard** said calling it from

```
componentWillMount() { this.props.screenProps.updateHeader(); }
```

instead of the constructor fixes the warning.